# How to generate APK file from Android Hybrid?

Tags: android, cordova, apk, hybrid-mobile-app

When I run this command `cordova build android --release` this gives me an error like:

> Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

How can I generate an APK file?

The application is built using Hybrid (PhoneGap and Android)

Comment: are you calling this function while being in projects folder?

Comment: In which directory do you execute the command? "An error **like**"? Pleas, if posting a error, post the correct error (copy -> paste), and not "something like"

Comment: Yes, i navigate into the project folder and run this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from the image, that you are running the command from Platform specific (Android) directory. See the image below of the directories the phonegap creates. The project directory is different. You need to run the build command from the **Project Directory**.
The sample project in the image is **pgdatabase1**.
N.B. The below directories are for **phonegap 3.4.x**
[image]

**Edit1:**
My guess is that the project has not been created using the command line tool (CLI). It has been created directly in Eclipse.
The **apk** file is present in the **MDLiveMobileAndroid\bin** directory.
Take a **backup** of the APK file before following the below steps.
1.Launch the Eclipse application.
2.Select the New Project menu item.
2.Choose **Android Project from Existing Code** from the resulting dialog box, from the **android folder** and press Next:
4.select the **MDLiveMobileAndroid** directory then click “Next”.
Select the projects that show there and click “Next”.
This should import the project’s into eclipse
5.Press Finish.
Once the Eclipse window opens, a red X may appear to indicate unresolved problems. If so, follow these additional steps:
1.Right-click on the project directory.
2.In the resulting Properties dialog, select Android from the navigation pane.
3.For the project build target, select the highest Android API level you have installed.
4.Click OK.
5.Select Clean from the Project menu.

This should hopefully correct all the errors in the project.

Comment: Can you see my package explorer. i am not able to see the platforms folder in it (note : am doing changes to this project but the original development done by other guy)

Comment: Yes exactly your are correct. I got this source code from my old colleague and i made few changes while i tried to get apk this error comes. Now i followed all your procedure (edit1) and still the problem persist.

Comment: @SampathKumar what error? can you be more specific.

Comment: Current working directory is not a cordova base project

Comment: @SampathKumar are you still using the command prompt for building the app?. If yes, than I have already said in my answer that the project has been built using eclipse. So you should be using eclipse IDE for building the app and not the command prompt. After you open the project in Ecplise, Right click the project in the `package explorer view`, Select `Run as Android application`, this should build your project if it does not contain any errors. It will then ask you to select an emulator device ( if you have configured) for running the app.

Comment: exactly now i got the differences